# hit or reach a plateau

Tags: word-usage, difference

What’s the variant the most idiomatic?

> The figures ***reached/hit*** a plateau

Are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: You could always [use NGrams to compare prevalence of the 4 permutations.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prices+hit+a+peak%2Cprices+reached+a+peak%2Cprices+hit+a+plateau%2Cprices+reached+a+plateau&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprices%20hit%20a%20peak%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprices%20reached%20a%20peak%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprices%20reached%20a%20plateau%3B%2Cc0) As you might expect, 10-cent ***peak*** is far more common than 50-cent ***plateau***, and "literal" ***reached*** is far more common than figurative ***hit***,

Answer (score 1):

These are not alternatives, they have completely different meanings.

And those meanings are the same as when those words are used literally:

- a plateau is a high flat area of land, so when figures reach a plateau they flatten out at a high level.
- a peak is the top of a mountain, so when figures reach a peak they go up and then back down.

Comment: *Peak* isn't mentioned in OP's question.

Comment: It was when I answered, OP has edited.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct for idiomatic usage. Which one is best depends on the context.

As the previous answer stated, in the literal sense, a ***plateau*** is *a high, flat stretch of land*. Idiomatically, it refers to *a 'leveling off' period of little to no change*. Both '***hit***' and ***'reach'*** can be used in this context, but each have their own subtle nuance:

1. '***Hit***' generally implies a negative meaning, i.e. you were making progress until you hit a plateau (similar to '*hitting a wall*' or '*hitting a roadblock*').
2. '***Reach***' is more neutral and often refers to data. For example,

> The number of new infections has finally reached a plateau.

In your case, it sounds like '***reach***' might be best, but either could work.